# How to use variable in SQLite Query

Tags: jquery, sqlite, variables

I am trying to figure how to replace (inputName) with a variable

```
db.transaction(insertNote);

  function insertNote(tx){
   // var note = document.getElementById('firstName').value;
   tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO leadsContainer(inputName) VALUES (?,?,?)",[pinValue,lat,lng]);

  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *can't* do what you have in mind with a prepared statement, as the table and column names are always fixed.  The placeholders `?` you have in the `VALUES` clause are fine.  Perhaps the closest thing to what you want would be to have logic which uses one of several fixed prepared statements, e.g.

```
var input = 'firstName';
if (input === 'firstName') {
    tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO leadsContainer(inputName) VALUES (?,?,?)", [pinValue, lat, lng]);
}
else {
    // execute some other prepared statement
}
```

Comment: @EmanuilYakimov The key point here is that the outside users of your application should not be directly controlling the SQLite code which your Node application is running.  They might be able to choose a certain query, but they don't get to write it.